# Como sacar un número fibonacci cada vez que das a un botón

Tags: jquery, fibonacci

He conseguido hacer un generador de números Fibonacci pero poniendo el valor en un formulario. A mi me gustaría un botón que cada vez que pulses vayan saliendo los números no poner un valor y que salgan. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

```
    <html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#boton").click(function() {
        var primer_numero = 0;
        var segundo_numero = 1;
        var tamanio = $("#numero").val();
        resultado = $("#resultado");
        var salida = '0,1';
        for (i = 0; i < tamanio - 2; i++) {
          var numero_siguiente = primer_numero + segundo_numero;
          salida = (salida + (",") + numero_siguiente);
          primer_numero = segundo_numero;
          segundo_numero = numero_siguiente;
        }
        $("#resultado").html(salida);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Introduce el número que quieras para sacar los números Fibonacci. </h1><br>
  <input type="text" name="value"  max="17" id="numero"></input><br>
  <button id="boton"> Submit </button><br>
  <h4>Output: <br> <span id="resultado"></span></h4><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Podrías usar una [función generadora](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) que para eso precisamente existen. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/556701/como-sacar-un-n%c3%bamero-fibonacci-cada-vez-que-das-a-un-bot%c3%b3n#comment983665_556701), podrías usar una [función generadora](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) que te devolverá siempre el siguiente número de la [Sucesión de Fibonacci](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucesi%C3%B3n_de_Fibonacci).

Por ejemplo, una función que genere los números de la Sucesión de Fibonacci puede verse así:

```js
function* fibonacci() {
    let first = 0;
    let second = 1;
    let third = first + second;
    while(true) {
        yield first;
        first = second;
        second = third;
        third = first + second;
    }
}
```

El resultado lo puedes ver en el siguiente `snippet`:

```js
function* fibonacci() {
    let first = 0;
    let second = 1;
    let third = first + second;
    while(true) {
        yield first;
        first = second;
        second = third;
        third = first + second;
    }
}
const fiboNumber = fibonacci();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#boton").click(function() {
        const value = $("#fibo").html() + `${fiboNumber.next().value} &nbsp;`;
        $("#fibo").html(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="boton">Obtener el siguiente número de la sucesión</button>
<br>
<div id="fibo"></div>
```

Como se aprecia en el código, utilizo 3 variables: `first`, `second` y `third` para almacenar los valores calculados en cada llamada a `next()`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Buenas Mauricio, muchísimas gracias por responder, me valdría perfectamente. Pero me surge otra duda, si quiero que vayan apareciendo pero no se borren, es decir, al lado o debajo como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Claro, es muy sencillo, en vez de sobre escribir el valor del `div` lo vas a concatenar.

Comment: @PedroAntonioAlegreDíaz he editado mi respuesta para mostrar los valores uno al lado del otro. Saludos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias compañero! Me queda clarísimo :)

Comment: Si la respuesta es válida, puedes [marcarla y votar positivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Eso te da reputación tanto a ti como a mi. Saludos